# How do I remove a stair tread under linoleum without damaging the linoleum?

Tags: flooring, stairs, vinyl-flooring

I'm replacing some old 1970s railing in between my kitchen and family room (there's a step down into my family room.)  I ripped that out and exposed what looks like a stair tread that was ripped down and used for the step-down edge.  I pulled that out because it was beat up and we are changing stain colors.  In the pic you can see the "anatomy" of what I'm working with:

[image]

So the edge sits on the joist and the fascia board.  (It was glued/nailed to the joist.)

Now my problem is that I need to get the other section out.  It looks like the linoleum is sitting on top of it...so how can I get that out and not damage the linoleum?  Undercut it with my multitool saw?  Or is that a fool's mission and should I attempt something else?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try heating a section near the edge with a hair dryer to see if it softens the adhesive.If you are lucky only the edges were glued.Use a stiff joint knife to gently lift the edge.

Comment: I think it's likely impossible. But, if anything will work it'll be this.